# make a simple login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, authentication

hey all..
i want to make a simple login page. I have prepared two textfield.

```
<input type="text" id="user">
<input type="password" id="password">
<input type="button" id="go">
```

i want after click #go script can check:

```
if #user value != "admin" 
then #password value != "qaubuntu"
```

will show and JS alert.
but if data same, will show some hidden .
can you show me how to do that?

Comment: So i'll start my comment with the last two words you ended your answer with: Please help - me understand what you actually want. Oh, in proper English. Use Google Translate for all we care.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(function() {
  $('#go').click(function() {
    if($('#user').val() !== "admin" || $('#password').val() !== "qaubuntu") {
      alert('Invalid login');
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

that's the quick fix (assuming you're just playing around). But you should never do it like this for a few reasons:

1. Anyone with half a brain can look at your JavaScript and see what the id/pw is
2. I always think it's better to do the user authentication at the server side
3. Probably a million others, it's so insecure it hurts

but for the purpose of this answer I'm assuming you're just practising with jQ.

Comment: +1, this is huuge security problem! But yes, the answer should do what has been asked.

Comment: yups..this is for the starter..could you give me some script that you mention at no.2?

Answer (score 0):

this is in jquery, when clicking on button #go check the login data

```
$('#go').bind('click',function()
{
   if($('#user').val() == 'admin' && $('#password').val() == 'qaubuntu'))
      //ok do what you need
   else
      alert('username or password not valid');
});
```